# CakePHP Parsing data from file and adding to database

Tags: cakephp

I have a file that I wish to parse and add to the database.

The way I wish to do it is this:

1. The user uploads the file
2. File is parsed
3. The users are given the parsed data and selects what they want to keep
4. They submit

(More detailed explanation follows)

I have a film script file that I wish to parse and enter scenes and their respective characters and props. I have already managed to parse this file into an array using php.

What I want to do now is to

1. prompt the user with the various scenes and its contents
2. allow the user to fix / modify the data before submitting it into the database.

The thing is that the script file has more than one scene in it, so I am unsure how to handle the data-entry aspect of this problem.

Are there any "best practices" for these kinds of data entries?

(if I didn't explain something in enough detail, please tell me and I'll update the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply parse the file and save it as it is to the database. Something like Script hasMany Scenes. Let them select their script and simply paginate the Scene records and let them delete them.

Is there an urgent need to *not* save them all after import? Another downside of your approach is that if the browser crashes or the user closes it he has to start over again because you just kept the data in memory but not persistant.

If you want to rely on your approach you'll have to work with the data coming back from the form and simply remove the key from the form data.

Like doing this in a foreach running over the data structure

```
if ($data['Scene][$key]['delete'] == 1) { unset($data['Scene'][$key]); }
```

Comment: Then need stems from the user wanting to modify some data or other ... so there is no real explicit need. I'll work with this approach and post my results.